# MS CRM 2015 Edit and show a custom entity record by id from another entity record iFrame using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

As the title says I want to show a custom entity record from another entity record through a standard CRM iFrame implementation.

I've tried to use the default settings when opening a record through a URL, example from the Account entity:

var iframeURL = "https://ORGANIZATION/main.aspx?etn=CUSTOM_ENTITY&pagetype=entityrecord&id=CUSTOM_ENTITY_ID";
Xrm.Page.getControl('IFRAME').setSrc(iframeURL);

But it doesn't work, the only thing the iFrame shows is a blue sort of navbar with no items and below the navbar the page is allways blank. And the logs says that there aren't any errors.

So is this even possible to do within a CRM system?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I dont think this supported.

[Open forms, views, dialogs and reports with a URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx)

> Displaying an entity form within an IFrame embedded in another entity
>   form is not supported.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Seems like I missed that little line of text from the documentation. Rethinking the solution it is!